# Power BI Embedded from Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, adal, powerbi-embedded

I'm working to connect to Power BI Embedded from an iOS and Android app written in Xamarin.

I was working through the example for 'App owns data' at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/get-azuread-access-token, however, the function UserPasswordCredential is not available to create an AuthenticationContext in the Xamarin version of C#.

My question: Is it a supported scenario to connect to Power BI Embedded from Xamarin. If so, pointers to docs / examples are welcome.

Comment: Here's a sample Xamarin.Forms app that I made to access PowerBI via AzureAD: https://github.com/brminnick/PowerBISampleApp

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. If I read your code correctly, it uses oauth to authenticate with AD. Is this correct ?
What I'm after is a way to authenticate with AD where the app holds the credentials. The use case is to enable the use case to embed Power BI in my app as defined at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers.

Comment: Hey Rajesh! You'll have to authenticate with AD to get a token. You can then store that token in local file storage on the device so that the app can continue referencing it. This app does store the token locally, but not in secure storage. I definitely recommend using secure storage for production apps!

Comment: Also, I don't recommend embedding Power BI into your mobile app, because Power BI is a web dashboard that doesn't scale well to mobile. The better tactic is to create a native mobile UI: pull the same data from Power BI and display it using the native mobile controls.

Comment: @BrandonMinnick Can you send links to examples/docs on how to pull PowerBI data and display it using native mobile controls in a Xamarin app?  Is this what your sample app above does?

Comment: @Rajesh Have you found solution for this? I'm having similar problem with my app

Answer (score 0):

You can find Sample [here](https://github.com/brminnick/PowerBISampleApp)

```
    public Task<AuthenticationResult> Authenticate(string authority, string resource, string clientId, string returnUri)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(returnUri);
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        var platformParams = new PlatformParameters(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity);

        if (authContext.TokenCache?.ReadItems()?.Any() is true)
            authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().Authority);

        return authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, uri, platformParams);
    }
```